# Select all except one impala

Tags: hive, hiveql, hadoop2, impala

I am finding the apporoach to ignore a column from Inner-select Query in Impala .

I am very well able to figure it out in Hive. Does anyone tried it in Impala ??

**Hive :**

```
 select `(col_name)?+.+` from  t1 ; -- To Except a Column in Hive .
```

**Impala:**

I tried the same format in Impala .But Its throwing the error saying

> "AnalysisException: Could not resolve column/field reference:
>   '(row_num)?+.+' "

Thanks in advance !!